# Make CRUD operations with ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have started to learn scala recently and trying to create simple api using akka HTTP and reactivemongo.
Have problems with simple operations. Spend a lot of time digging docks, official tutorials, stackoverflow etc. Probably I am missing something very simple.

My code:

```
object MongoDB {
    val config = ConfigFactory.load()
    val database = config.getString("mongodb.database")
    val servers = config.getStringList("mongodb.servers").asScala
    val credentials = Lis(Authenticate(database,config.getString("mongodb.userName"), config.getString("mongodb.password")))
    val driver = new MongoDriver
    val connection = driver.connection(servers, authentications = credentials)
    //val db = connection.database(database)
}
```

Now I would like to make basic CRUD operations. I am trying different code snippets but can't get it working.

Here are some examples:

```
object TweetManager {
    import MongoDB._
    //taken from docs
    val collection = connection.database("test").
        map(_.collection("tweets"))
    val document1 = BSONDocument(
        "author" -> "Tester",
        "body" -> "test"
    )

    //taken from reactivemongo tutorial, it had extra parameter as BSONCollection, but can't get find the way of getting it
    def insertDoc1(doc: BSONDocument): Future[Unit] = {
        //another try of getting the collection
        //def collection = for ( db1 <- db) yield db1.collection[BSONCollection]("tweets") 
        val writeRes: Future[WriteResult] = collection.insert(doc)
        writeRes.onComplete { // Dummy callbacks
            case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
            case Success(writeResult) =>
                println(s"successfully inserted document with result: $writeResult")
        }
        writeRes.map(_ => {}) // in this example, do nothing with the success
    }
}
insertDoc1(document1)
```

I can't do any operation on the collection. IDE gives me: "cannot resolve symbol". Compiler gives error:

```
value insert is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection]
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the `insert` operation on a `Future[Collection]`, rather than on the underlying collection (calling operation on `Future[T]` rather than on `T` is not specific to ReactiveMongo).

It's recommanded to have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html).